# Is there any advantage of defining the size of Arraylist while instantiating

Tags: java, arrays, collections, arraylist

Is there any advantage of defining the size of Arraylist while instantiating .?

Please correct me if am wrong or if its a duplicate of possible other questions . I searched but I couldn't find what I was looking for .

Is it an advantage of defining the initial capacity of Arraylist. Its 10 by default I guess.

While resizing the Arraylist will it help if we declare while instantiating . Also how to potentially overcome the overhead of resizing of Arraylist internally.?

Comment: Scanning through Javadoc for it, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ensureCapacity(int)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ArrayLists use arrays internally, so when an ArrayList needs additional capacity, it has to create a new array internally and copy the elements over to the new array.

You can overcome the overhead of resizing the ArrayList by estimating or finding the exact size of the ArrayList beforehand. Alternatively, you can make sure the ArrayList never grows beyond a specified size by handling your business logic and then removing elements whenever your ArrayList is at its maximum desired size. Finally, you can use a different data structure that does not use arrays internally to avoid your growth problem altogether.

Comment: I would not propose (Java) LinkedList as an alternative, it uses more memory and has worse average performance, even when just inserting at the end (memory allocation per list item, with allocation overhead and extra pointer for the link to next element).

Comment: @hyde I do know what a linked list is. You are correct that ONE element in a LinkedList would take more memory than ONE element in an ArrayList. However it is not necessarily correct to say that overall it takes more memory, since an ArrayList grows according to an algorithm when it needs to expand, whereas a LinkedList offers controlled growth one element at a time. My point was merely that there are tradeoffs involved in any choice of data structure, not that he should use LinkedList.

Comment: I did not measure myself, so I may be wrong here, in which case I'd love to be corrected: As far as I know, about 4 items is the limit where `LinkedList` starts to use more memory than ArrayList with default initial capacity. And like 501 items in `LinkedList` take more space than 501 elements in an ArrayList with capacity 1000. And yeah, I agree otherwise, my point (opinion) is that `LinkedList` should be avoided even as an example, it's *very* rarely a good choice. Even the constant time insertion isn't, because Java GC may kick in.

Comment: @hyde You're right. Edited my answer. Thanks for your persistence. :) I'm not sure about the exact details of the memory usage, but I was thinking in terms of objects not references. ArrayList holds references to Objects not the Objects themselves. Therefore the allocated space is just enough to hold the reference.

Answer (score 7):

If you know the capacity you need, providing it up front could improve performance. Otherwise, as you add elements, the list implementation might need to copy the internal array to one of larger size -- possibly repeatedly.

Comment: Arraylist usage should we always overlook the problem of internal resizing or is there any possible way to handle it .?

Comment: @Suraj In almost all cases you should overlook it. If you have a use case where you're afraid of running out of memory then perhaps you need to use a different data structure. Similarly, if you have a use case where the time cost of resizing an ArrayList's internal array might be cost prohibitive, then you also need to consider other data structure and algorithms.

Comment: Amortized across multiple insertions, the cost is guaranteed to be O(1). If this is an issue, you can provide the initial capacity, or use a different data structure.

Answer (score 2):

Specifying initial capacity for `ArrayList` can and will improve performance if used right. If used wrong, it can hurt performance.

It is worth doing for example, if you are creating new `ArrayList` instances in a loop *and* know how to calculate the real final size, or a reasonable starting size.

But usually it is either not worth it, or even harmful:

- If you allocate too much "defensively", memory use and initialization cost can be more than cost of resizes with default size.
- If code evolves and ideal list size changes, but you forget to adjust the custom initial capacity, then optimisation can become pessimization.
- The time you spend on micro-optimization like this is usually better spent on something else.
- The average cost is constant per appended element: because size doubles, each element in the list has *on average* been moved just once (right before resize) or twice (right after resize). Usually processing the objects put to the list is many times more costly, so overall impact of resize is irrelevant.

---

For the uses where indexable array is a good option, `ArrayList` is basically as good as it gets.

`LinkedList` in particular may *seem* better for some cases, but it's not! It has bigger memory overhead (extra allocation per list item!), and as a result worse performance on average even for cases where it's supposedly efficient, and even LinkedList insert at end is not guaranteed O(1) in Java, because GC may kick in at allocation. It is good fit only for very special cases, such as some concurrent algorithms.

One optimization is sometimes possible: If you have `ArrayList` of boxed primitive type (like `ArrayList<Integer>`), consider using primitive type array (like `int[]`). This does not actually overcome the resize issue, but it avoids the overhead of the boxed instances. But this only applies to primitive types, not for example `Strings`.

You can also create custom `List` if you can live with some extra restrictions you can take advantage of. For example, if you are willing to increase access time (from direct index access to one extra lookup) and only need to insert or remove at the ends, you can create a custom `List` implementation which is internally `ArrayList` of plain arrays. So when you insert, and an internal array fills, you create a new array and insert there, instead of reallocating the old array. But due to the overhead of two-level structure, this is rarely an overall improvement, and would more realistically be an alternative to using a `LinkedList` (which, again, is right choice very rarely).

So in general, if `ArrayList` resize is problem, best cure to *that* is to get beefier computer ;). Another solution is to improve the overall algorithm, or in general improve performance otherwise (because the total performance is what matters, not isolated performance of some small detail).

---

It's interesting how this has actually changed from the "olden days" of computing. With interactive applications, you want some operations to happen within some real world time limit, so user experience does not suffer. With slower computers, array list resize would be too time-consuming at quite a small list size.

But CPU and memory performance have improved faster than typical list item counts, so something like one-time resize of a million element list is no problem: it's moving mere 4/8 megabytes when memory access speeds are measured in gigabytes per second.

Also, multi-threading has become more common, and worst-case response time of non-interactive threads doesn't really matter, it's more about overall throughput, as long as UI thread stays snappy. So if you are handling large data like that, it is often better to move data handling elsewhere (another thread, a real database) than try to optimize list operations in the UI thread.